# "Warning: file_get_contents" in WAMP2 (Apache2.4.4, PHP5.4.12)

Tags: php, web-services, html-parsing, wamp

I am trying to get content of the web page with simple:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
echo $result;
```

but I get this warning and no content in the `$result`:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com): in C:\wamp\www\google\google_search.php on line 76
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  277824  {main}( )   ..\google_search.php:0
2   0.0106  757640  file_get_contents ( )   ..\google_search.php:76
```

In my PHP.INI I have allowed the "url_fopen":

```
allow_url_fopen On  On
```

I am using "Apache 2.4.4" and "PHP 5.4.12" (last build from WAMP website) on x64 WIN machine.
I can't figured out what is causing my problems.

Comment: do `var_dump($result)`. you'll probably find it's a boolean FALSE, meaning the call failed. Could be anything, even something like your server/firewall preventing outbound http requests

Comment: Yes, I am getting `boolean false` when dumping the var. I really don't understand what is going on, because I have full admin right on my PC where WAMP is running and I can make outbound HTTP request via my browser. I also tried to allow the WAMP for my outbound and inbound connections and then also disable Windows Firewall. Nothing has helped.

Comment: Did you restart WAMP services after setting `allow_url_fopen` to on ? By the way, a much proper way to work with external URLs is cURL : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php. You won't have to deal with such `fopen` errors this way.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted WAMP services afterwards, but nothing had changed. The reason why I haven't even try with cURL is that I have already many php files on my server written using the function `file_get_contents (...)` and I knew it must be just some stupid mistake I am doing wrong. By the way, I have answered my question by myself and thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have resolve this issue by myself.

In my php code, I have manually set php.ini settings via `ini_set(...)`. One of the settings is `'default_socket_timeout'` and it was imported from working php file on WIN machine (WAMP2.2, PHP 5.4.3, Apache 2.4.2) where I wasn't experiencing any problems with the function `file_get_contents(...)`. The value was set to `0`, meaning  `default_socket_timeout=0sec` and NOT `default_socket_timeout=infinite sec` as one could conclude from other php.ini definitions (e.g. ['max_execution_time'](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)). So, as the result of exporting the php file from WAMP2.2 to WAMP2.4, I also need to set `default_socket_timeout` to some positive value (e.g. 5 sec), since newer WAMP(or maybe PHP, or Apache?) is treating the initialization differently.